# Can I remote upload URLs to Ubuntuone account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

There is a file on Internet which weighs 3GB, and I need it to directly transfer that file to My UbuntuOne account.. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question: I highly doubt that you could do that because it works a lot like Dropbox where it downloads to your computer and then uploads to their server. I am pretty sure there isn't a way to do that...there is a php script that can do server to server but I don't know if it would work with UbuntuOne or not...though I doubt it would. I'll tell your the script in email or twitter if you want...not sure if script writers want it advertised or not.

Comment: what did you edit? looks the same as before.